# ADF Not Copying Some tables in the pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have 1000+ tables.

I have been using multiple pipelines to from source to destination.

I am copying each and every bit of data in one go.

My source is on-premise SQL server and the destination is ADW.

Some of my tables have been copying with no errors, but some of them are not getting copied to ADW; tables are being created but with no data in them.

I can see the produced slicer it stats the Data Read but no Data written inside the ADW.

Did something like this happen to anyone?

Answer (score 0):

You need to share your pipeline and dataset details here. Also, turn on errorlogs and see of there's an issue in the underlying data itself.

Comment: Share my pipline? 
I have over 1000 tables plus 11 pipeline how am i suppose to share the all the data set here???

Comment: You can share one snippet here, I am sure all the others are pretty similar. You need to provide something for us to help you here.

Answer (score 0):

If you take the dataset(s) that is generating the blank table(s) out and run it on it's own in a separate pipeline does it work?  Is it failing only while running along side all the other ones?